# What differences modelEvents and this.model.on

Tags: marionette

```
        var ContactManager = new Marionette.Application();

        ContactManager.addRegions({
            mainRegion: "#main-region",
            child:"#child2"
        });

        Ar  = Backbone.Model.extend({});
        Se = Backbone.Model.extend({});
        Articlescollection = new Ar({ product_id: "104", title: "Test title"});
        SelectedsCollection = new Se({ product_id: "71", title: "Test title"});


       ContactManager.StaticView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: tpl2,
            tagName: "div",
           model:Articlescollection,
           modelEvents: {
               'change': 'fieldsChanged'
           },
           fieldsChanged:function(){
               console.log('dddd')
           },

           initialize: function () {
              this.model.on('change', this.render);
           }
        });


        ContactManager.StaticView2 = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: tpl2,
            tagName: "div",
            model:SelectedsCollection
        });


        var MyLayout = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
            template: tpl3,

            regions: {
                menu: "#menu",
                content: "#content"
            }
        });

        ContactManager.on("start", function() {



           // ContactManager.mainRegion.show(  new MyLayout     )

            var layout = new MyLayout
            ContactManager.mainRegion.show(  layout )
            layout.menu.show(new ContactManager.StaticView());
            layout.content.show(new ContactManager.StaticView2())

            Articlescollection.set("product_id", 24) 
//init fieldsChanged trigger for change model
        })

        ContactManager.start();
```

What differences between modelEvents and this.model.on ?

they both initizlized when model was change but

modelEvents: {
       'change': this.render
   },

throw exception Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

`modelEvents` is the same as `this.listenTo(this.model, { 'change': 'fieldsChanged' });`  It is just sugar so you don't have to add that to `initialize`.  You should probably *never* use `this.model.on` inside a view.  That would not get cleaned up automatically like `this.listenTo` would.  Other than `this.on` I don't think `on` should be used in general as `listenTo` is much safer.

The other major difference here is that:

```
var model = this.model;
var view = this;
this.model.on('change', function() {
  this === model; // true
  this === view; //false
});
```

The only reason this would work with `render` is because `render` is forcibly bound to the view by marionette.  Any other function would have a different scope.  You can change the scope by passing it as the 3rd variable of `on`, but again then you need to `this.model.off` in `onBeforeDestroy`

If you want to call `render` from `modelEvents` you have a few options:

```
modelEvents: {
  'change': 'render'
}
//or
modelEvents: function() {
  return {
    'change': this.render
  };
}
// or 
modelEvents: {
  'change': function() { this.render(); }
}
```